# how to set state array with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Thanks In Advance.
Am new to react hooks (REact Native)

Iam maintaining 2 state array, 1 has the list of item to be displayed and another one is the list user selects from 1st array.

```
const [myList, setMyList] = React.useState([
        {
            ID: 0,
            AddName: 'Zion 1'
        },
        {
            ID: 1,
            AddName: 'Zion 2',
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            AddName: 'Zion 3',
        }
    ])

    const [userSelectedList, setUserSelectedList] = React.useState([])
```

How do i have a function for a flatlist render onclick, if user selected 1 item it should get in to the state `userSelectedList` and if user click that again the item should be removed from `userSelectedList`.

Am not keeping my code here as its so shaggy. Can anyone help me out with the exact login and syntax to work with.

```
const itemOnClick =(item) =>{
//logic --setState
}
```

State mutation is a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`const [userSelectedList, setUserSelectedList] = React.useState(null)`

```
const itemOnClick =(item) =>{
  item !== null ? setUserSelectedList(item) :setUserSelectedList(null)
}
```

but if you are using select element I preferred to make a react reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [userSelectedList, setUserSelectedList] = React.useState([]);

const itemOnClick =(item) => {
   if (userSelectedList.length === 0) { 
      setUserSelectedList(item)
      return;
   }
   const arrId = myList.map(item => item.id);
   if(arrId.includes(item.id)) {
      const newArrUserSelected = userSelectedList.filter(val => val.id !== item.id)
      setUserSelectedList(newArrUserSelected)
   } else {
      setUserSelectedList([...userSelectedList, item])
   }
}
```

Hope to help you!